# Selectize Js trigger "selectize-dropdown-content" div

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

Using this plugin https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js for this dropdown.

On load, it have to check country detected. if detected country "AU", it have to trigger option with id="AU".

Tried my best to trigger.. but my script didnt work for auto trigger. it have to trigger "selectize-dropdown-content" div container to trigger.

**HTML**

```
<select name="select" id="select" >
 <option id="EN" value="global.html">Global</option>
 <option id="AU" value="australia.html">Australia</option>
 <option id="ID" value="Indonesia.html">Indonesia</option>
</select>
```

**In browser it render as below format:**

```
<select name="select" id="select" class="custom-select elem-width selectized" placeholder="Select Country" data-validation="required" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
  <option value="others.html" selected="selected"></option>
</select>

<div class="selectize-control custom-select elem-width single">
  <div class="selectize-input items full has-options has-items">
    <div data-value="others.html" class="item">Others</div>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" style="width: 106px; opacity: 0; display: inline-block;">
  </div>
  <div class="selectize-dropdown custom-select elem-width single" style="display: none; visibility: visible; width: 235px; top: 40px; left: 0px;">
    <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
        <div data-value="others.html" data-selectable="" class="option selected">Others</div>
        <div data-value="US.html" data-selectable="" class="option">United States (US)</div>
        <div data-value="kr.html" data-selectable="" class="option">Korea</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function getCode () {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var uniqueNumber = now + 'a' + randomNumber;
    $.getScript("getCountryCode.js?" + uniqueNumber, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        if (country){
           var code = country;
           console.log("countryCode:" + countryCode);
           $('.selectize-dropdown-content div').trigger('change');
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: the rendered html doesnt have the ids? try using something like this `$element.selectize.setValue("YOURVALUE")`

Comment: Thanks for your hint Cerlin.. Will check this and get back to you.